# Should "status-completed" appear in the subject?

Tags: feature-request

If the suggestion on meta has been implemented, it will be good to see [completed]  in the     end of the subject, similar as it shown for [closed] questions.

It would be more explicit, than only "status-completed" tag.

It also will be visible in "Related" list on the right side of the page.

Clarification: I have not noticed the tag for particular request(probably, because I do not often use meta site). I read all discussion and voted that it is a good idea, and only later realised, that it is already implemented. This is a reason for my suggestion.

UPDATE: I see many people down-vote my suggestion. Please note that many users are not familiar enough with meta site and special tags in particular, so make the status more obvious will be useful for them.

Comment: +1 I agree with Kevin that it isn't necessary, but I would like to see it anyway as a "nice to have".

Answer (score 7):

I think that it's not necessary because the red mod tags stick out so much. They don't just blend into the rest or the background, they really pop out at you.

Comment: However I have not noticed it(probably, because I do not often use meta site), and it is a reason for my suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim How do you know what `status-completed` is if you've never seen it?

Comment: @Paulpro, I’ve seen the status-completed before, but I haven’t noticed it on particular question.  Sorry for the very late answer :).

Comment: Ah, I see. Also, it's only been a little over six years... no big deal.